# call javascript function on website

Tags: javascript, http-post

I want to call Example() on a website in javascript in a way so I can loop it every couple seconds. I know how to do the loop but have no idea how to actually call the function itself on the website

Comment: Elaborate more on what your trying to do.  Tell us the entire flow of your program

Answer (score 0):

Use `setinterval` finction Like This:

```
setInterval(Function(){
   Example();     //your function
}, 2000);         //2 sec interval
```